# Finite Poincare transformation in momentum space?

Tags: special-relativity, poincare-symmetry

In position space, a finite Poincare transformation changes the coordinate four-vector $x^\mu$ as

$$x^\mu\to x'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu x^\nu+a^\mu$$

where $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$ is a Lorentz transformation matrix and $a^\mu$ is a finite translation parameter.

I was wondering how this translates into momentum space with momentum four-vector $p^\mu$? Do we also just have

$$p^\mu\to p'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu p^\nu+b^\mu$$

as in position space? I assume $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$ is the same Lorentz transformation matrix as in position space, but what is $b^\mu$ here? Clearly, it cannot be the same as $a^\mu$, since it must have different mass dimension. Perhaps my assumption is wrong, and the transformation actually looks different in momentum space?

Comment: Ask yourself this: If the space transformation is just a translation, what happens to the momentum?

Comment: @Javier Seeing as $p^\mu=m\partial_\tau x^\mu$, with proper time $\tau$, and $a^\mu$ is constant, it would suggest $b^\mu=0$. However, momentum space is dual to position space, so I would have expected to be able to set 10 non-trivial parameters in the transformation, instead of just 6 due to Lorentz transformation. Any hint how to make sense of this?

Comment: I think that what this shows is precisely that symmetries don't necessarily act the same way on position and momentum space: they are not equivalent in every way.